# Show Only Published Posts in Post Index View

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've got a Post model/view/controller/templates in my Phoenix application with the following schema:

```
  schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string
    field :content, :string
    field :published, :boolean
    belongs_to :user, MyApp.User

    timestamps
  end
```

Currently in `web/controllers/post_controller.ex` I've got this:

```
def index(conn, _params, user) do
  projects = Repo.all(MyApp.Project)
  render(conn, "index.html", projects: projects)
end
```

My `templates/post/index.html.eex` file lists all of the posts; however, what I'd like to do is only show the posts that are published (posts where published is equal to true).

I know that I need to change this line in the index action - but I'm not sure what to change it to. What is the best practice for this in Phoenix/Elixir?

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by modifying `web/controllers/post_controller.ex` like this:

```
  def index(conn, _params, user) do
    projects = Repo.all(from u in Project, where: u.approved == true)
    render(conn, "index.html", projects: projects)
  end
```

I'm not sure whether or not this is the right way/best way to achieve the result; however it does work. Please comment and let me know or post another answer if there is a better way.

Comment: This is pretty much it for your case. I don't recall a better way. But I have some suggestions:

- It's good practice to alias models that you will use often in a controller
- As an exercise try to build a filter (if true show only published if false show all) for you index action.

Comment: Yeah, filter would be great. You would be able to shorten it to `Repo.all(Project.approved)`

Comment: can one of you provide an example? will accept as an answer if you do. thanks :)